# How to write type constraints that match several case classes with different signatures

Tags: scala, types, static-typing

Suppose I have some case classes that share a single trait:

```
trait MyCaseClasses {
  def generic: String
}
case class C1(l: List[Int], generic: String) extends MyCaseClasses
case class C2(s: String, generic: String) extends MyCaseClasses
case class C3(a: Int, b: Int, generic: String) extends MyCaseClasses
```

What I want to do is create a function that takes any one of these case classes as an argument. Something like:

```
def caseClassCurry[T <: MyCaseClasses](generic: String, cc: T): (args) => T = {
  (args) => cc(args, generic)
}
```

Of course, this doesn't compile. There are two problems here that I don't know how to solve:

1. `args` is difficult to specify. It has to represent a variable number of arguments of any type. How would you do that?
2. When I write out versions of this I get `cc.type does not take parameters`. I'm assuming this is because `cc` only inherits the qualities of `MyCaseClasses` which is a trait and doesn't take arguments - the type system can't infer that a class that inherits the trait might have arguments. I need to have some way of indicating that `cc` does, in fact, take arguments (see question 1). How would I accomplish this?

Optimally, I would like to change the trait `MyCaseClasses` to indicate that classes that extend it will have any number of additional arguments of `Any` type, but how that would be accomplished is also unclear.

Comment: This is more than likely possible, though not necessarily easy. You will probably need shapeless to do this. https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Comment: Why do you need this? Wouldn't be easier to just call the constructor directly? I assume all the information is dynamic, thus I would just write an simple factory method that return an option or either.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez If you can find a clean way of accomplishing similar functionality over N case classes using Option/Either I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Logister what do you really need? Which information is static which is dynamic. Which is the format of the dynamic one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
scala> trait F[T]{ def generic: String }
// defined trait F
scala> case class C1(l: List[Int], generic: String) extends F[List[Int]]
// defined case class C1
scala> case class C2(s: String, generic: String) extends F[String]
// defined case class C2

scala> def caseClassCurry[T](generic: String, cc: (T, String) => F[T]): T => F[T] = cc(_, generic)
def caseClassCurry[T](generic: String, cc: (T, String) => F[T]): T => F[T]

scala> caseClassCurry("c1", C1.apply)(List(1, 2, 3))
val res2: F[List[Int]] = C1(List(1, 2, 3),c1)
```

** EDIT **
Sorry for missing the `C3` case in the above solution, I have found another solution but only works in `dotty` (i.e. scala3.0). It may work by using `shapeless` in scala2:

```
scala> trait F { def generic: String }
// defined trait F

scala> case class C1(generic: String, list: List[Int]) extends F
// defined case class C1

scala> case class C2(generic: String, str: String) extends F
// defined case class C2

scala> case class C3(generic: String, a: Int, b: Long) extends F
// defined case class C3

scala> def curry[T <: Tuple, C <: F](generic: String, cc: String *: T => C): T => C = t => cc(generic *: t)
def curry[T <: Tuple, C <: F](generic: String, cc: String *: T => C): T => C

scala> curry("hello", C1.apply.tupled)(Tuple1(List()))
val res0: C1 = C1(hello,List())

scala> curry("hello", C2.apply.tupled)(Tuple1("world"))
val res1: C2 = C2(hello,world)

scala> curry("hello", C3.apply.tupled)((0, 1L))
val res2: C3 = C3(hello,0,1)
```

Comment: Thats very close - I can adapt this, but it doesn't work for variable number of initial arguments (see C3 from my example) correct? I'd have to wrap multiple argument cases with their own sub case classes. E.g.: `case class C3arg(a: Int, b: Int); case class C3(c3arg: C3arg, generic: String) extends F[C3arg]`

Comment: @Logister I have updated my answer for the `C3` case.